# Problem understanding intuitively a measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

I have troubles understanding the following definition:

> Let $\mu$ be a measure on $\mathbb{R}_+\mapsto \mathbb{N}$ (meaning from the Borel $\sigma$-algebra) and set $$T_n(\mu):=\inf\{t\geq 0:\mu([0,t])\geq n\},\quad n\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\}$$
>   where $\inf \emptyset := \infty$. Let $\mathbf{N}$ be the space of all such measures $\mu$ from $\mathbb{R}_+\mapsto \mathbb{N}$ such that $\mu([T_{\infty}(\mu),\infty))=0$ and $T_{n}(\mu)<T_{n+1}(\mu)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$
>    such that $T_{n}(\mu)<\infty$

1. I don't really understand the last thing. What exactly does $\mu([T_{\infty}(\mu),\infty))=0$ mean? And is there an intuitive understanding of such counting measures?
2. And does $T_{\infty}(\mu)<\infty$ mean we have $\mu([0,t])\geq \infty$ for some suitable $t$, meaning a finite set with infinite measure?

Comment: Is $\mu$ assumed to be a measure that takes its values in $\mathbb N$? If so, $\{ t \geq 0 : mu([0,t]) \geq \infty \} = \emptyset$ so $T_\infty(\mu) = \infty$ and $\mu([T_\infty(\mu), \infty)) = \mu([\infty, \infty)) = \mu(\emptyset) = 0$ automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way, in my opinion, of thinking about counting measures by thinking of them as, well, counting particles.  From here, it becomes more clear what these properties mean:

Let's think about $\mu([T_\infty(\mu),\infty)) = 0$.  $T_\infty(\mu)$ is the smallest number so that there are infinitely many particles to the left of it.   In the case where $T_\infty(\mu) = \infty$, we have that every finite subset contains finitely many particles, and tautologically $\mu([T_\infty(\mu),\infty)) = 0$.  When $T_\infty(\mu) < \infty$, it says that we have a buildup of particles occurring in a finite time.  In this case, $\mu([T_\infty(\mu),\infty)) = 0$ says that, yeah, there might be a huge buildup, but there are no more particles after that buildup.  For instance, if you put particles at each point $1 - 1/n$ for each $n$, then $T_\infty(\mu)$ would be $1$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Consider, for example, a measure $\mu$ on $[0,\infty)$ such that $\mu(B)=\int_B{1\over 1-x}\,dx$ whenever $B$ is a Borel subset of $[0,1)$. Then $\mu([0,t])=\log(1/(1-t))$ for $0\le t<1$, so $T_n(\mu) = 1-e^{-n}$ for $n=1,2,\ldots$, and $T_\infty(\mu) =1$. Whether $\mu([T_\infty(\mu),\infty))$  is equal to $0$ depends (unlike $T_\infty(\mu)$) on whether $\mu$ puts any mass in $[T_\infty(\mu),\infty)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.